# Proving Square-Integrability of X Using Characteristic Function of X - Y (X and Y are i.i.d)

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

This is a problem I encountered in an exercise about the application of characteristic function: The first question asks me to prove that the characteristic function of $X - Y$ is real-valued and non-negative when $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d random variables.

Given this, I have to prove that $X - Y$ being square-integrable implies that $X$ is square-integrable, which in this case is equivalent to show $|\mathbb{E}[X]| < \infty$.

If I am to prove this using characteristic function, I have to show that $\frac{d}{dt} \mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]$ exists, yet I have no idea about how to get this from $\mathbb{E}[(X - Y)^2] < \infty$. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: I don't know how to do it using characteristic functions but there is a simple proof using Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks a lot! I have worked it out using Fubini's Theorem, yet I still wonder if there exists another way to prove this.